# How to share Chatter File (ContentDocument) with set of Users

Tags: public-group, chatter-file

As per salesforce documentation, record can be created in ContentDocumentLink

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm

LinkedEntityId - ID of the linked object. Can include Chatter users, groups, records (any that support Chatter feed tracking including custom objects), and Salesforce CRM Content libraries.

We have User Group (Not CollaborationGroup), want to share that file with that group. Is it possible to do that? If yes, How ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the ContentDocument that the link points to in order to share the File with other Users or Groups. See [ContentDocument](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm).

Comment: Although documentation says Groups, but User Groups are not allowed, these seems to be CollaborationGroup

Comment: I think you need to look at the Object Reference. Particularly [CollaborationGroupFeed](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_collaborationgroupfeed.htm).